# Question about equivalence of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$ be two sets and $B^A$ be the set of all functions that maps $A$ into $B$. How to prove that
$\{0,1\}^A$ is equivalent to $P(A)$ (the power set of $A$)?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/how-to-show-equinumerosity-of-the-powerset-of-a-and-the-set-of-functions-from). Also it is more common to call such sets equinumerous.

Answer (score 2):

There is a natural bijection between the two. For any subset $K$ of $A$, define $f_K$ by $f_K(x)=1$ if $x\in K$, and $f_K(x)=0$ otherwise.

The mapping $\varphi$ that takes $K$ to $f_K$ is a bijection from the power set of $A$ to $\{0,1\}^A$.